# Can the compendium of SE Q&A’s be translated into an encyclopedia?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-analysis

Stack Exchange has become quite the concentration of years of Socratic knowledge - that is to say, having many questions asked, answered, and peer reviewed to some degree - of the main site pages.

I am think of something that is either translated in a wiki, done through an algorithm. I don’t know about A.I. tech, but it seems to reaching a degree of processing analysis, perhaps. I am not proposing modifying the SE community’s Q&A format, but mining into a different form.

Is there a current method to analyze these series into a more encyclopedic form from the current message board data?

Are there any current methods of evaluating the overall quality, accuracy and confidence in the community on SE?

If yes or no to either, please expound.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) (which was [Sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation), but still perhaps related)

Comment: I'd suggest keeping it under subject headings. Then make it searchable by keywords. Oh, wait...

Comment: Encyclopedias are rarely organized into question and answer format themselves; they're largely presented as-is/in-situ with respect to the topic (think "semiconductor", "Java", "parallelism").  More times than not, the best question-and-answer pair is one that builds on each other.  What value do you believe restructuring answers from the site into an encyclopedic format would bring?

Comment: I agree that explaining what purpose this could have would improve the question post. Is the [FAQ home post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/997587) something like what you are imagining? Or are you imagining something more dramatic in format difference? I.e. Are you talking just about _compilation_ (which the FAQ home post is), or actual _rewriting and maintaining in a different framework_ (something different than Q&A)? Re-writing and maintaining would be a huge amount of work that I don't really see being feasible.

Comment: Okay I totally misunderstood this post the first time I read it. I thought you were talking about meta discussions on MSE. Now I see eyou're talking about each network site's main (non-meta?) site. You're asking two questions. For your first, I think it would help if you described in more detail what you are imagining it to look like. For the second, the answer is yes: [Voting](/help/why-vote).

Comment: Are the down votes because it’s a bad idea or is there some issue to which I could improve the question?

Comment: @EliotGYork Meta convention tends to be downvoting things you disagree with

Comment: @EliotGYork In addition to the feedback I already gave, see [What is Meta Stack Exchange, and how does it work? - Voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/997587)

Answer (score 6):

Well - quite a *lot* of what we do won't translate at all into an 'encyclopedia' - or in a more modern context, a wiki-type site.

An encyclopedia gives a broad overview of a subject. A Q&A pair gives a specific, directed problem and potential solutions for it. The scope is narrower.

I guess it's almost like the difference between a movie, a TV series and a short - each tells a 'story' but in different ways and different focuses, and while you can use one as a basis for another, it's certainly not going to translate 'perfectly' between mediums.

> I am think of something that is either translated into a wiki, done through an algorithm. I don’t know about A.I. tech, but it seems to reaching a degree of processing analysis, perhaps. I am not proposing modifying the SE community’s Q&A format, but mining into a different form.

Looking at the state of machine learning, that might... take a while. *Ideally* the translation from 'Q&A' to 'other formats' is in showing how a specific knowledge artifact from our Q&A site(s) translate into part of solving a bigger problem. It's quite the opposite of mining, and in many cases, the human touch is essential.

In some of my personal projects - I've asked a question over something I was stuck with, then, used that answer as *a part* of the process of trouble solving.

Humans are *very good* at creating and finding problems and hammering away at solving them. AI... tends to fall flat here, to the point where 'prompt engineering' is a skillset to try to get the output you want from a ML system.

Practically speaking, as such that transition does happen *when you use knowledge from here to solve a problem*, then document it. It's something that's best organic rather than forced.

Comment: Thank you. One part I was thinking was that it’s in some ways conversational having a Q&A format. I thought that might fit the ML format because the computer can receive the question as if it was asking, and then receive the answer as if it was getting a response. I thought that was a method applied to the learning process, conversational learning.